# Cannot login to admin with custom backend in Django 1.11.rc1

Tags: django, django-admin, python-3.6

Using `Django 1.10` I have no problem using my custom backend to login (not a custom user just the auth) but in `1.11rc1` I get the following exception:

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version:     1.11rc1
Exception Type:     FieldError
Exception Value:    

Cannot resolve keyword 'request' into field. Choices are: clientcontact, crudevent, date_joined, email, <...just more fields>
```

The backend:

```
    def authenticate(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            username = kwargs.pop("username", None)
            if username:
                username_or_email = Q(username=username) | Q(email=username)
                password = kwargs.pop("password", None)
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get(username_or_email, **kwargs)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
                else:
                    if user.check_password(password):
                        return user
        else:
            ...
```

In `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('base_app.auth_backend.JbcBackend', 'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',)
```

I haven't been able to find anything, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.
Here is the full Traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/handler.py" in process_exception_by_middleware
  237.             return super(AsgiHandler, self).process_exception_by_middleware(exception, request)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  393.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in dispatch
  90.         return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  182.         if form.is_valid():

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  385.         self._clean_form()

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  412.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
  187.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  100.             user = backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)

File "/home/mat/PycharmProjects/jbc_services/base_app/auth_backend.py" in authenticate
  19.                     user = User.objects.get(username_or_email, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  370.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  781.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  799.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1260.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1286.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1164.         lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in solve_lookup_type
  1044.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())

File "/home/mat/.virtualenvs/jbcarcenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in names_to_path
  1362.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'request' into field. Choices are: clientcontact, crudevent, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, logged_in_user, loginevent, password, thirdpartycontact, user_bookmarks, user_permissions, user_preferences, username, userobjectpermission
```

Comment: Try looking up user only with username_or_email (without kwargs) and then also verify the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username_or_email)
    # The user is found, now check if the password matches
    if user.check_password(password):
        return user
except User.DoesNotExist:
    pass
...
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'll need to have a deeper look in to why.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid `request` is now passed as a `kwarg` to authenticate that's why.

Comment: @SimonCharette Thank you!